# Display Wordpress avatar for logged-in user on post/page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to display a logged-in user's individual avatar/gravatar (based on their email address) on one of my pages.

So far, I've only been able to find methods to display the page author's avatar, or the same avatar for all users.

I gather that I need to add get_avatar to my functions.php, using something like this:

```
< a href = "<?php echo get_author_posts_url($post->post_author); ?>"
title = "<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author ); ?>" >
  <? php
if (get_the_author_meta('user_custom_avatar', $post - > post_author) != '') { ?>
  < img src = "<?php the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $post->post_author ); ?>"
  alt = "" / >
    <? php echo $curauth - > display_name; ?>
  <? php
} else {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  echo get_avatar($current_user - > user_email, $post - > post_author), '80');
} ?>
< /a>
```

But I also need to know how to display it in the content of my page/post. Is there something I can use include when editing the page using Wordpress?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to use to fetch avatars.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33121/get-avatar-of-the-logged-in-user-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

In any page or post just call it like this

```
 $custom_avatar = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_custom_avatar', true);
```